# Intermittent Boot Failure on Windows After Forced Shutdown

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, freeze, shutdown

The problem started when my computer froze while playing a game, forcing me to perform a hard shutdown. Since then, booting up has become a gamble; it sometimes boot up and works normally and other times just a black screen.

Here's what happens: I power on the PC, and the Dell logo appears as usual, but then the screen goes blank, and it gets stuck without booting into Windows. This requires another hard shutdown. Typically, after two attempts, the Windows Advanced Options menu appears. From here, I can boot into Safe Mode without issue. Interestingly, after booting into Safe Mode and then restarting, the PC sometimes boots normally, and I can use it as if nothing's wrong.

Additionally, my pc also goes blank when it wakes up from sleep. Sometimes the PC freezes on the lockscreen

However, this issue isn't confined to Windows. I have Ubuntu installed in dual boot, and it has its problems too. When I attempt to boot into Ubuntu, I encounter a persistent error message: "`Bug: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 22s! (nvidia-persiste:689)`". This prevents Ubuntu from booting up completely.

To solve this I have tried resetting windows to default using Windows Advanced Options Menu. But the PC froze during the reset process at 9% fortunately windows was able to undo changes and I'm back where I started.
Any Ideas why this issue might be coming? and any potential solutions?
I'm running **Dell Inspiron 5577** laptop.

Comment: It would appear the hard shutdown damaged the boot area. Since reset did not work, you most likely have to start fresh.

Comment: Run `chkdsk` and verify the SMART attributes of the disk (you may add them in your post for a second opinion). Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).